# as3 Problems adding caps to linestyles

Tags: actionscript-3, lines

My project allows the user to "draw" lines with their mouse (and I mean straight lines, no curves etc.) I want them to be able to choose the type of caps the line has. Here is what I have.

```
var board: Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(board);
board.graphics.lineStyle(sizeSlider.value, selectedColor, alphaSlider.value,false,"normal","square");
```

board is the graphic object the lines are being drawn on. Why don't the lines have square caps when drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right, so are you sure that caps is not drawn? If the line is thin, it will not be seen visually almost no difference between various caps. It is well illustrated by the documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/CapsStyle.html.

If all OK, check that lineStyle do not changed after your code elsewhere.

Comment: You are right, I had other lineStyles in later code that switched them back to normal. Thanks.